# set and store password in android apps

Tags: android, passwords, sharedpreferences

I have try to set and store the password for my apps, but it is not working at all. The password should be setted first time then return the home page, then when the user open it again the password should be stored but somehow it didn't store it.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences passfile = getSharedPreferences("ans",0);
    String pass = passfile.getString("ans", null);

    check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String answer1 = answer.getText().toString();


            //Check that user typed in an answer
            if(answer1.length()<8){
                Toast.makeText(CheckPwActivity.this, "Answer must be 8 characters long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                answer.setText("");
                answer.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            answer.getEditableText().toString();
            //check if the answer is valid
            if (answer1.equals("ans")) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(CheckPwActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);


        }else{ 
            return;

        }


    }});



    }
public void setPassword(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Editor preferenceEditor = context.getSharedPreferences("password", 8).edit();
    preferenceEditor.putString(key, value);
    preferenceEditor.commit();
}

public static String getPassword(String filename) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences("password", 2).getString(filename,"");
}
```

Comment: how do we know you are using the same key in the set / get password methods?

Answer (score 0):

you are using shared preferences wrong, in your set password you get shared preferences but then you get it again but in a different context

this is all you need to use shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

then when you want to set it you use the editor you just got

```
editor.putString(key,pass).commit;
```

then to get it from shared preferences you would just do

```
preferences.getString(key,defaultString);
```